# Selected Values into database using Entity framework from Repeater

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have situation, in which i need to get selected values from the radio button list inside the
repeater control. my problems is that i have more then one Rows in repeater but when i add the selected values to the database it inserts data only from one row. here is my code.

```
 public double evalute()
    {
        qresponsedetail responses = new qresponsedetail();
        qrespons qresponse = new qrespons();
        qresponse.quizid = quizid;
        qresponse.suerid = username;
        qresponse.score = 0;
        context.AddToqresponses(qresponse);
        context.SaveChanges();

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                string ansid = (item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1") as RadioButtonList).SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
                string qid = (item.FindControl("qid") as HiddenField).Value.ToString();

                responses.responseid = qresponse.responseid;
                responses.answerid = Convert.ToDecimal(ansid);
                responses.questionid = Convert.ToDecimal(qid);
                context.AddToqresponsedetails(responses);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

My second requirement is that how i can add all selected values into a list and then insert using EF. i m using context.savechanges twice in the function, how i can achieve same with only one context.savechanges. thanks

Comment: You're changing the same object `responses` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public double evalute()
{

    qrespons qresponse = new qrespons();
    qresponse.quizid = quizid;
    qresponse.suerid = username;
    qresponse.score = 0;
    context.AddToqresponses(qresponse);
    context.SaveChanges();

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == 

ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
qresponsedetail responses = new qresponsedetail();               
 string ansid = (item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1") as           RadioButtonList).SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
            string qid = (item.FindControl("qid") as HiddenField).Value.ToString();

            responses.responseid = qresponse.responseid;
            responses.answerid = Convert.ToDecimal(ansid);
            responses.questionid = Convert.ToDecimal(qid);
            context.AddToqresponsedetails(responses);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```